# How do I convert String to an Object in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

In my Mongo database, I have a "Books" collection with a "category" field. In the past, "category" was an enum mapped as String in Mongo but now I need "category" to be an object within my "Books" collection. What can I do? Is there a query that can be executed to convert all documents at once?

Example, today category is like that:

```
"category" : "Sci-Fi and Fantasy"
```

But I need to convert to this:

```
"category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("3f07bc56po324021df23a8f1"),
        "code" : NumberLong(1),
        "name" : "Sci-Fi and Fantasy"
    }
```

Comment: Do you have categories collection where you can get other fields to build the new objects?

Comment: I have historical data in which "category" was an enum. But from now on this field will be filled as an object. It's a change in the business rule, I have nowhere to get the fields from the object to fill in this historical data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is no SQL you can have both kind of records present in your mongo collection, although while reading the records you might have to frame some logic for creating identical entities. This might cause issues if you search based on that particular property.

You can create a new property with different name keeping the category as well and then add the new property to all the records.